# CodeIgniter: bad headers - Improper use of control character

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp

Здравствуйте! После перехода с одного почтового сервера на другой письма, отправляемые с сайта, стали приходить с ошибкой

> bad headers - Improper use of control character (char 0D hex): From: 
>   ...=d0=b0=d0=ba=d0=be=d0=b2_\r?=\n =?UTF-8?Q?=[...].

Ранее всё всегда работало нормально. Сайт на CodeIgniter. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Также в теме сообщения почему-то неправильная кодировка:
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: smtp

```
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
```

Date: Tue, 9 Jun 2015 18:13:29 +0500

From: "No replay"

Return-Path:

To: mail@1111.ru

Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?=d0=9a=d0=be=d0=bd=d1=82=d0=b0=d0=ba=d1=82=d0=bd=d0=b0=d1=8f_
?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?=d1=84=d0=be=d1=80=d0=bc=d0=b0_=d1=81_=d1=81=d0=b0=d0=b9=d1=82
?=
 =?UTF-8?Q?=d0=b0?=

Reply-To: "noreplay-1111-ru@inbox.ru"

X-Sender: noreplay-1111-ru@inbox.ru

X-Mailer: CodeIgniter

X-Priority: 3 (Normal)

Message-ID: <5576e679a680b@inbox.ru>

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

----------------------- ОТ -----------------------

ФИО: Тест   Контакты: Тест

----------------------- СООБЩЕНИЕ -----------------------
Тест

Answer (score 2):

Могут быть несколько вариантов.

1. Новый e-mail сервер в другой ОС. тут влияет значения `\r`  и `\r\n` проверьте эти значении.
2. Может быть некоторые модули устарели и нужно обновить. Так как некоторые email сервера не принимают пустые строки в `header` сообщения.

но без кода трудно что то сказать

P.S.

Для первого пункта.

> \n - Используется в Unix системах как конец строки
>
> \r  - Используется в Mac системах как конец строки
>
> \r\n - (слитно) Используется в Windows и DOS системах как конец строки.

Comment: Спасибо!
 по первому пункту стоит: $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";

Comment: попробуйте поставить `\n`

Comment: я пробовала, возникают  ошибки и письмо вообще не отправляется